# Exception Handling vs performance

Tags: c#, performance, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance Cost Of 'try' in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867017/performance-cost-of-try-in-c)

Hi 
lets say two similar codes (func A calling B, B calling C, C calling D and so on) are available with following slight difference:
CODE 1: no try catch finally block is writen in code.
CODE 2: each method has a try catch block within.

if no exception is thrown, is there any performance difference?

thanks.

Comment: Forget performance: there is a semantic difference. The two pieces of code have different behaviors. You cannot compare a fast program that outputs garbage with one that works correctly.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: What? Who said either approach output garbage?

Comment: yes, true. there is semantic difference. but they have same behaviors.

Comment: @Azodious: They don't have the same behavior. When there is an error in the first execution terminates. When there is an error in the second you do something with it. @Lazarus: because the two behave differently, it's more important to get the one that has the desired behavior than the one that doesn't.

Comment: @Martin
i agree, but in question i said that no exception in thrown. so do they have same behaviour?
output-wise : YES
performance : looking for answer.

Comment: @Azodious: oh, my missed. I somehow missed the part about no exception thrown. Sorry for the confusion.